# LEFT JOIN: error in getting the userid from the session

Tags: mysql

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`left join image on gallery.gal_id=image.gal_id WHERE`' at line 3

could appreciate some help

```
SELECT username,count(image.img_id) as no,gallery,gallery.gal_id 
FROM user 
left join gallery on user.userid=gallery.userid 
left join left join image on gallery.gal_id=image.gal_id
WHERE userid = '" . $_SESSION['userid'] . "'";
```

Comment: You have `left join` repeated twice in the fourth line of the query.

Comment: Thanks for that, I have removed it. now the error showing                             You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'userid'] . "'"' at line 5

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the query that you want to write:

```
SELECT u.username, count(i.img_id) as num, gallery, g.gal_id 
FROM user u left join
     gallery g
     on u.userid = g.userid left join 
     image i
     on g.gal_id = i.gal_id
WHERE u.userid = '" . $_SESSION['userid'] . "'";
```

However, it has a potential problem.  This query will always return exactly one row, because it is an aggregation query with no `group by`.  However, if a user can have multiple galleries (which is not clear), then only one will appear, arbitrarily, in the `SELECT`.  If this is a problem, you have to decide what you want to happen.  I would suggest that you ask *another* question, with sample data and desired results.